# Правильный порядок jobs

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

К примеру у меня есть скрипт, который билдит и тестирует код с помощью одной image. Тогда по завершению первой стадии раннер просто перейдет ко второй. Но что если я хочу использовать сразу несколько `image`? Чтобы, к примеру, сначала сбилдило и протестило с помощью `gcc`, а потом с помощью `mingw`?

Вот мой скрипт:

```
cache:
  paths:
    - build

stages:
  - build
  - test

.build_template: &build_definition
  script:
    - mkdir build
    - cd build
    - cmake ..
    - cmake --build . -- -j4
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - build/bin
      - build/lib

.test_template: &test_definition
  variables:
    DISPLAY: '0'
  script:
    - Xvfb :0 -fbdir /tmp &
    - cmake --build build --target test
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - build/Testing


build:linux:
  image: andrejlevkovitch/u18qt512:latest
  stage: build
  <<: *build_definition

test:linux:
  image: andrejlevkovitch/u18qt512:latest
  stage: test
  <<: *test_definition

build:mingw:
  image: andrejlevkovitch/mingw64qt512:latest
  stage: build
  <<: *build_definition

test:mingw:
  image: andrejlevkovitch/mingw64qt512:latest
  stage: test
  <<: *test_definition
```

При этом в этом случае я имею такую структуру:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тобишь они перекрестно свзязаны, вместо того, чтобы связять build и test только для соответственных image. Как это сделать правильно?